# Java Regex entering infinite loop

Tags: java, regex

I have a paragraph on which i am trying to apply a regular expression. Unfortunately its entering into an infinite loop. Could you please let me know what is wrong with this regex.

Regex,

```
(([A-Z]\w*[\s\.\u0026]*){1,}\s(\d{4})|(\d{4})\s([A-Z]\w*[\s\.\u0026]*){1,})\s(\(\d+\))\s(\d+)
```

Paragraph,

> WHEREAS Dr. L. S. Meena, Scientist C Gr. IV(2) has been convicted on
>   criminal charge under section 815.04(4)(A) Offence against
>   Intellectual Property during his stay in USA under BOYSCAT Fellowship
>   and has been awarded a sentence to serve 24 day(s) in the Orange
>   County Jail with credit for 24 day(s) time served w.e.f. 22nd March,
>   2005 by the CIRCUIT COURT OF THE NINTH JUDICIAL CIRCUIT, IN AND FOR
>   ORANGE COUNTY, FLORIDA, USA.

Also can you tell me is there any tool that could tell me if there are any loopholes in the regex written?

Thanks,
Harsha

Comment: What is this regex supposed to be doing?

Comment: Problems may be arising from regex like `{1,}` for once or more times, you would be better using x+, x+? or x++. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) for information about quantifiers in java.

Comment: @SeanKenny That can't help as those are nothing but synonims.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Agreed but they do the same thing in subtly different ways.

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/Tet97UhR4T Rubular suspects this regex will take forever to parse. Regexes of this sort make Rubular sad.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a 'pathological' regex, i.e. it suffers from catastrophic backtracking because of the repeated repeats, such as `([A-Z]\w*[\s\.\u0026]*){1,}`.

Catastrophic backtracking is explained here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html